# Showing continuity of a function that depends on another continuous function.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

Question: please help me pointing out the errors of my proof (I'm sure there are some). The proof is structured in cases (two cases with each two subcases) and I think that some may be correct but others won't. So instead of just writing a different proof I would be thankful if you could point out errors in the specific cases and correct them eventually.

Let $a,b \in \mathbb R$ with $a<b$. Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a continuous function.

Define the function $M:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$  as $M(x):=$ max$\left \{f(t):a\leq t \leq x\right \}$. Show that $M$ is continuous.

Divide the proof in two cases. First case $f(x_0)<M(x_0)$ and second case $f(x_0)=M(x_0)$.

First case: $ \ \ \exists s_0 \in [a,x_0)$ with $f(s_0)=M(x_0)$. Let $\delta_0:=x_0-s_0$.Then we have $M(x)=M(x_0), \forall x \in [x_0-\delta_0,x_0]$. 
Hence we have$ \forall x \in [a,x_0],|x-x_0|<\delta_0 \Rightarrow |M(x)-M(x_0)|=0$.

We also know that $\exists \delta_1$ s.t $|x-x_0|<\delta_1 \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon_0$ (since $f$ is continuous), with $\epsilon_0:=M(x_0)-f(x_0)$.
So we have $|x-x_0|< \delta_1 \Rightarrow f(x)<f(x_0)+ \epsilon_0 :=M(x_0)$.
In particular for $x \in [x_0,b]$ with $|x-x_0|<\delta_1$ we have $|M(x)-M(x_0)|=0$.

Summarizing the above results by which we analyzed the situation for $x\in [a,x_0]$ and then for $x \in [x_0,b]$ we have the following result: $\forall \epsilon>0,|x-x_0|<min\left \{ \delta_0,\delta_1 \right \} \Rightarrow |M(x)-M(x_0)|=0<\epsilon$. By which we have continuity of $M$ for the first case.

Second case:

For $x\in [a,x_0]$ we have:

$f(x)\leq M(x) \Rightarrow -M(x)\leq -f(x) \Rightarrow 
M(x_0)-M(x) \leq M(x_0)-f(x) \Rightarrow 0\leq M(x_0)-M(x)\leq f(x_0)-f(x) \Rightarrow |M(x)-M(x_0)|\leq|f(x)-f(x_0)|$.Hence with continuity of $f$ we get the continuity of $M$.

For $x \in [x_0,b]$ we define $M(x):=f(s)$ for some $ s\in [x_0,x]$.
With continuity of $f$ we have: $\forall \epsilon >0 \ \exists \delta , |x-x_0|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|< \epsilon$. Hence $x \in [x_0,x_0+\delta) \Rightarrow |f(s)-M(x_0)|<\epsilon \Rightarrow |M(x)-M(x_0)|<\epsilon$. By which we have again continuity of $M$.

Comment: Your function $M$ is constant. It does not depend on $x$ at all.

Comment: A typing error. Edited.

Comment: I am unable to find a single flaw in the proof. I tried, but I cannot find it. The only slight inconsistency is that you "define" $M(x):=f(s)$ for some $s\in[x_0,x]$. You don't really get to define $M$, it's already defined. You just know that indeed, $M(x)$ does equal $f(s)$ for some $s\in[x_0,x]$. You may need to write an extra sentence around that point.

Comment: One more thing: in the first case, all you need is the $\delta_1$ you found in the second paragraph. Basically, you can shorten your proof by deleting the first paragraph (the one starting with "first case:") and the third paragraph ("Summerizing the above"), while replacing $\forall x\in[a,x_0]$ with $\forall x\in[a,b]$.

Comment: You should also make sure the proof works when $x_0 = a$ or $x_0 = b$

Comment: @5xum thanks a lot for your advice. Consider converting the two pieces of comment into an answer, if you like.

Answer (score 1):

The proof, in general, is correct. It is generally visible from it that you understand why $M$ is continuous and are able to prove it.

There are only two small issues I could find. The first is in your analysis of the first case, where you needlesly complicated your proof, making it confuzing. The $\delta_1$ you found in the second paragraph of the first case actually tels you that every value of $x$, so long as $|x-x_0|<\delta_1$, shares the property that $f(x)<M(x_0)$. There is nothing limiting you to the right side of $x_0$, therefore, this $\delta_1$ is all you need to finish the first case of your proof.

The second issue is an inconsistency in writing when you wrote the last paragraph. There, you wrote that you "define" $M(x):=f(s)$ for som $f\in [x_0, x]$. Since $M$ is already defined, you cannot define it again, so I believe what you tried to say here is that you know that $M(x)$ is equal to $f(s)$ for some $s$. It would be nice to show why this is so.