# Reference to an elementary result of mathematical analysis.

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, continuity, reference-works, publishing

Can anyone suggest a mathematical analysis textbook that contains proof of this **Proposition** below?

I have already sought proof of this result in classic textbooks of mathematical analysis such as Rudin and Zorich, but without success.

**Background.** Let $I^{n}\overset{_\mathrm{def}}{=}\left\{x=\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}\right) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}|\;\;a_i\leq x_{i} \leq b_{i}\,;\; i=1, \ldots, n\right\}$ be an $n$-dimensional closed interval and $I$ a closed interval $[a, b] \subset \mathbb{R}$.

> **Proposition.**  Let $f \in C^0(I^n\times I,\mathbb{R})$. Then the function
> $$ 
>    m(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},x_{n},y)=\min_{t\in [y,b] } f(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},x_{n},t) 
> $$
> is also continuous on the  $I^n\times
> > I$.

Here the number $m(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},x_{n},y)$ means that for any fixed point $(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},x_{n})\in I^n$ we have $ m(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},x_{n},y) \leq f(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},x_{n},t) $ for all $t\in [y,b]$.

Comment: I have not seen this in the usual analysis texts, but have seen it in many optimisation notes, books, etc. It is straightforward to prove (for example, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/674559/27978) and can be generalised quite a bit.