# Prove a min function defined in the domain of another continuous function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Assume a min real function is defined below:

$$
f(x)=\min\limits_{x\leq y\leq h(x)}g(y)
$$

$g(x)$ is continuous. $x\geq 0$, $h(x)=ax+b$, $a\geq 1, b\geq 0$. Prove $f(x)$ is continuous.

---

This is a problem I recently encountered when reading a paper. There may be several scenarios regarding the location of $y^\ast$ ($g(y^\ast)=\min\limits_{x\leq y\leq 2x}g(y)$) in the domain $[x-\delta, 2x+2\delta]$. And we may prove the continuity by discussing the different scenarios. My proof is below:

---

$\textit{Proof}.$

We must prove that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$, such that when $|x-x_0|<\delta$,

$$|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$$

Because $g(x)$ is continous, for any $\epsilon_1>0$, there exits $\delta_1$, when $|x-x_0|<\delta_1$,

$$|g(x)-g(x_0)|<\epsilon_1\tag{1}$$

$g(x)$ is also continous on $x=h(x_0)$. There exists $\delta_2$, when $|h(x)-h(x_0)|<\delta_2$,

$$|g(h(x))-g(h(x_0))|<\epsilon_2\tag{2}$$

For any two number $x_1$, $x_2$ in the domain $[x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta]$, let $\delta\leq \delta_1$, we can get

$$
\begin{aligned}
|g(x_1)-g(x_2)|&=|g(x_1)-g(x_0)+g(x_0)-g(x_2)|\\
&\leq |g(x_1)-g(x_0)|+|g(x_0)-g(x_2)|<2\epsilon_1
\end{aligned}\tag{3}
$$

For any two number $x_1$, $x_2$ in the domain $[x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta]$, because $h(x)=ax+b$,

$$
\begin{aligned}
a(x_0-\delta) +b\leq h(x_1)\leq a(x_0+\delta)+b\\
a(x_0-\delta) +b\leq h(x_2)\leq a(x_0+\delta)+b
\end{aligned}
$$

When $\delta\leq \delta_2$, then $h(x_1), h(x_2)\in[h(x_0)-\delta_2, h(x_0)+\delta_2]$, by Eq. (2), we can get

$$
\begin{aligned}
|g(h(x_1))-g(h(x_2))|&=|g(h(x_1))-g(h(x_0))+g(h(x_0))-g(h(x_2))|\\
&\leq |g(h(x_1))-g(h(x_0))|+|g(h(x_0))-g(h(x_2))|<2\epsilon_2
\end{aligned}\tag{4}
$$

Assume
$$g(y^\ast_{0})=\min\limits_{x_0\leq y\leq h(x_0)}g(y)$$

$$g(y^\ast_{\Delta})=\min\limits_{x_0-\delta\leq y\leq h(x_0+\delta)}g(y)$$

For any $x\in [x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta]$,

$$g(y^\ast_{x})=\min\limits_{x\leq y\leq h(x)}g(y)$$

Apparently, $g(y^\ast_{\Delta})\leq g(y^\ast_{x})$, $g(y^\ast_{\Delta})\leq g(y^\ast_0)$.

And $f(x)=g(y^\ast_x)$, $f(x_0)=g(y^\ast_0)$.

So,

$$
\begin{aligned}
|f(x)-f(x_0)|&=|g(y^\ast_x)-g(y^\ast_0)| \\
&= |g(y^\ast_x)-g(y^\ast_\Delta)+g(y^\ast_\Delta)-g(y^\ast_0)|\\
&\leq |g(y^\ast_x)-g(y^\ast_\Delta)|+|g(y^\ast_0)-g(y^\ast_\Delta)|
\end{aligned}\tag{5}
$$

According the location of $y^\ast_\Delta$, there are three cases possible for $| g(y^\ast_x)-g(y^\ast_\Delta) |$ :

(a).  $y^\ast_\Delta= y^\ast_x$, if $y^\ast_\Delta\in [x, h(x)]$.

In this case, $| g(y^\ast_x)-g(y^\ast_\Delta) |=0$.

(b). $y^\ast_\Delta\in [x-\delta, x]\subset [x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta]$.

In this case, let $\delta\leq \delta_1$, $| g(y^\ast_x)-g(y^\ast_\Delta) |\leq | g(x)-g(y^\ast_\Delta) |<2\epsilon_1$. (because of Eq. (3))

(c). $y^\ast_\Delta\in [h(x), h(x_0+\delta)]\subset [h(x_0-\delta), h(x_0+\delta)]$.

In this case, let $\delta\leq \delta_2$,

$| g(y^\ast_x)-g(y^\ast_\Delta) |\leq | g(h(x))-g(y^\ast_\Delta) |<2\epsilon_2$ (according to Eq. (4)).

Therefore, from the three cases, when $\delta\leq\min\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$, we can get

$$| g(y^\ast_x)-g(y^\ast_\Delta) |<\max\{2\epsilon_1, 2\epsilon_2\}$$

Because $g(y^\ast_0)$ is a special situation of $g(y^\ast_x)$ when $x=x_0$, there is also

$$|g(y^\ast_0)-g(y^\ast_\Delta)|<\max\{2\epsilon_1, 2\epsilon_2\}$$

Eq. (6) can be written to be:

$$|f(x)-f(x_0)|<2\max\{2\epsilon_1, 2\epsilon_2\}$$

Let $\max\{\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2\}=\epsilon$, we can get $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$. The continuity of $f(x)$ is proved.
$$\hspace{300pt}\Box$$

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I have edited this question. Is it qualified now?

Comment: Not really. Where is the “include your work and thoughts on the problem” part?

Comment: f(0) = g(0).  What is f(-1)?

Comment: I have edited the problem, now the function is defined only for the positive domain.

Comment: I found my question is very similar to this one: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673540/showing-continuity-of-a-function-that-depends-on-another-continuous-function?rq=1), the author provide a version of proof.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have edited my own thoughts to the problem. @WilliamElliot